# Saving Excel rows into lists in Python

Tags: python, excel, list

I basically want to save (for each row) the first 5 cells as floats to a list (say list1) then the sixth cell to another list (list2), then save both these to a list (list3). I want to do this for each rows and save each list3 for each row to one final list (sorry I know I said list alot),

So for example, for the data in the photo (labelled excel data below), I want to save it as:

```
final_list = [[[1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5],[1.6]], [[2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5],[2.6]],[[3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5],[3.6]]]
```

if that makes sense? What would be the easiest way to do this, I am a beginner at python.

[excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzti0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most common way of working with tables in Python is [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html#getting-started). If you just want plain lists [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62476889) that uses [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) might tell you what you need.

For your case would be something like this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path_to_wb = ...
my_wb = load_workbook(path_to_wb)

first_sheet = my_wb.worksheets[0]

whole_list = []
# Iter all the rows
for i in range(5):
    # Get first columns
    first_columns = [first_sheet.cell(row = i + 1, column = j + 1).value
                     for j in range(5)]
    
    # Create a list with one single element, last column
    last_element = [first_sheet.cell(row = i + 1, column = 6).value]

    # Add a list with two elements
    whole_list.append([first_columns, last_element])
```

If you would prefer a list comprehension, you can get rid of the loop:

```
whole_list = [[[first_sheet.cell(row = i + 1, column = j + 1).value for j in range(5)],
               [first_sheet.cell(row = i + 1, column = 6).value]]
              for i in range(5)]
```

Let me point out that this is what you asked for, but it is not the usual methodology for working with tables in Python.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want:

Assuming data is a 2D list where each row contains 6 elements

```
data = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
        [7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0],
        [13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0]]
```

Initialize empty list to hold final results

```
final_list = []

for row in data:
    # Extract the first 5 elements of the row and convert to floats
    list1 = list(map(float, row[:5]))
    
    # Extract the 6th element of the row and append to list2
    list2 = [row[5]]
    
    # Combine list1 and list2 into a single list
    list3 = list1 + list2  # might be [list1, list2]
    
    # Append list3 to the final list
    final_list.append(list3)
```